# Find all lists that look up a Contacts list

Tags: web-services, lookup-column, rest

I have a Contacts list in my site collection, and it is used in lookup columns by multiple other lists.

Is there an easy way to get all the lists that have a lookup column pointing to the Contacts list?

Comment: You need to get this lists using web service or using SP object model?

Comment: @AlexChoroshin preferably client side (soap, jsom, REST), but if there's a server side technique that doesn't involve looping through all lists and columns I'd be interested to know too.